# CSS Pseudo Selector for input:focus WITH text

Tags: css, input, focus, state

How do I keep styling of :focus after user inputs text and clicks out?

```
input[type="text"]{
    background-color:transparent;
}
input[type="text"]:focus{
    background-color:white;
    box-shadow:  3px 3px #red;
}
```

Comment: `input[type="text"]{...}`

Comment: @VitorinoFernandes Misunderstanding. Edited.

Comment: When the user clicks out it goes to the default state i.e `input[type="text"]{..}`. In your case you need to write a script to add class on focus so that the class remains even when focus is lost.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to use Javascript. What I did below is add a class when the input is clicked:

```
<style>
input[type="text"]{
    background-color:transparent;
}
input[type="text"]:focus,input[type="text"].focus{
    background-color:white;
    box-shadow:  3px 3px #red;
}
</style>

<input type=text id=myinput>

<script>
// can't use the 'click' event because it'll wait for the user to release the mouse
document.getElementById('myinput').addEventListener('mousedown',function() {
    if(this.value)
        this.className='focus';
},false);
</script>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/99dgvebv/1/

**Edit:**

Added `if(this.value)`.

Comment: What happens if the user didn't enter any text ? And the fiddle doesn't work

Comment: I changed it by adding `if(this.value)` :)